# CentOs 7 YUM update not working

Tags: centos, yum

I am trying to do a `yum update` and all of the mirrors fail with a 404.  I put the url into my browser and the error is correct, the url does not exist.  YUM is looking for a package that does not exist on the mirrors.  See below for the error message:

```
https://mirrors.lug.mtu.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/13b91b1efe2a1db71aa132d76383fdb5311887958a910548546d58a5856e2c5d-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.oss.ou.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/13b91b1efe2a1db71aa132d76383fdb5311887958a910548546d58a5856e2c5d-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/13b91b1efe2a1db71aa132d76383fdb5311887958a910548546d58a5856e2c5d-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/13b91b1efe2a1db71aa132d76383fdb5311887958a910548546d58a5856e2c5d-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/13b91b1efe2a1db71aa132d76383fdb5311887958a910548546d58a5856e2c5d-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://kdeforge2.unl.edu/mirrors/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/13b91b1efe2a1db71aa132d76383fdb5311887958a910548546d58a5856e2c5d-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
https://muug.ca/mirror/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/repodata/13b91b1efe2a1db71aa132d76383fdb5311887958a910548546d58a5856e2c5d-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://fedora.westmancom.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/13b91b1efe2a1db71aa132d76383fdb5311887958a910548546d58a5856e2c5d-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
https://ca.mirror.babylon.network/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/13b91b1efe2a1db71aa132d76383fdb5311887958a910548546d58a5856e2c5d-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
https://mirror.chpc.utah.edu/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/13b91b1efe2a1db71aa132d76383fdb5311887958a910548546d58a5856e2c5d-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
```

I have tried running `yum clean all`  That command finished successfully, but it did not change any thing.  I have also tried the following:

```
rm -f /var/lib//rpm/__db*
rpm --rebuilddb
```

That also did not change anything.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/yum.conf` file and add

```
http_caching=packages
```

**Explanation:**

`http_caching` option controls how to handle any HTTP downloads that YUM does and what yum should caches. Its default setting is to cache all downloads and that includes repo metadata.

So If the metadata file gets corrupted during download (exp: it is partially downloaded), yum will not be able to verify the remote availability of packages and it will fail.

The solution is to add `http_caching=packages` to /etc/yum.conf so yum will only cache packages and it will download new repository metadata each time.

Comment: may I ask why? What does this do? Has no explanation as to how it helps :/

Comment: "A wizard never reveals his secrets", he thought.

Comment: @xcy7e I added the explanation. You can check it.

Answer (score 18):

The following also works:

```
yum clean all
yum makecache
yum update
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a VM that hadn't been updated in a long while, and doing a `yum makecache fast` and `yum update` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Ran below command and the yum install worked successfully after that:

```
yum clean all
```